# Why Bootstrap defines @brand-primary with darken()?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In the Bootstrap file `variable.less`, some colors are defined this way:

```
@brand-primary:         darken(#428bca, 6.5%); // #337ab7
@brand-success:         #5cb85c;
@brand-info:            #5bc0de;
@brand-warning:         #f0ad4e;
@brand-danger:          #d9534f;
```

What is the point of using `darken()` for `@brand-primary`, why not just write directly `#337ab7`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original color was darkened for accessibility contrast on link colors. It was done in [this commit](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/eb74a8cbf363699eb822057650ddff2f36765ec9#diff-a7693b847cd07d7aa4c819d11e5becc1L17) by [Mark Otto](https://github.com/mdo). From the discussion:

> The `@brand-primary` could have been simply replaced with the default
>   value, but I wanted the source of the new color value to be left there
>   for context. The darker primary blue increases accessibility across
>   the board; the link change was merely the focus and impetus for this
>   change.